# What is the verb for 'competence' in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I think the following sentence is incomplete. What would be the best way to complete it?

> Effective communicator and efficient team-worker with competence through self-initiatives.

Should the word 'competence' be followed by 'built'/'gained'?

Comment: Technically, it's not a sentence, so rules for sentence formation wouldn't apply. (it's close to a headline or a bullet point.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for résumé/CV writing advice.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With minimalist changes, either could be used:

Effective communicator and efficient team-worker perform with competence acquired through self-initiatives.

Effective communicator and efficient team-worker perform with competence attained through self-initiatives.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Or you could say "...competent through self-initiative"

Comment: These aren't sentences either...